# Android setText of multiple TextView from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've used the `AsyncTask` example from [vogella website](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask), I've created a class file with it.
I'm calling it from `Activity A` to update the postalcode's `TextView`, it's working.

I'm wondering how can I call the same `AsyncTask` from `Activity B` to update another postal code `TextView`.

So one `AsyncTask`, 2 calls from different `Activities` to update different `TextViews`.

I've to do something `onPostExecute()`, right? 
Some example code, is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some effort code would be appreciated also. Without seeing what you have, have you tried to do the same thing in activity b that you did in a to populate it? Create an instance and start the thread...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (I guess) pass the TextView to the AsyncTask when you instantiate it.

All without the IDE open so apologies if the syntax is off...

```
public class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private TextView targetTextView;

    public ExampleTask(TextView target) {
     targetTextView = target;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... orSomething) {
      //do work and get a value I guess
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      targetTextView.setText(result);
    }
  }
```

Then you'd call this:

```
ExampleTask task = new ExampleTask(theTextViewToUpdate);
task.execute();
```

You'd want to be careful about the scope of the task objects you instantiate as that reference to a TextView could end up leaking memory from your activities.

Answer (score 0):

**Here I am  not good, but you can try**

It is possible to reuse AsyncTask for different Activities.
For this you must take different parameter from different Activities.
In AsyncTask Class initiate a constructor with a case parameter (which is described in other activities) which will decide ,it is called by Activity A or B or C.
Now use switch case statement and move ahead.